# Strange behaviour of radiobuttons with application settings

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, settings, application-settings

I have one form with two radiobuttons and I use the CheckedChanged event to display information. Everything works fine.

The problem arrives when I create two application settings and bind each of them to the Checked property of each radio button. After doing this, the behaviour of the radiobuttons starts to be strange. In particular, when I click the unchecked one, the checked one is unchecked, but the unchecked one remains uncheked! I mean:

- Checked --> Unchecked
- Unchecked --> Unchecked!!

It also has problems to load the previous state between executions, even though I use the My.Settings.Save and Load() methods.

Has anyone found this problem before? Do you have any clues about what is happening?
Thanks!

Comment: If you have TWO settings tied to TWO radios it sounds like you are using the wrong control.  If both settings are OFF then so should be both radios.  Radios are more for determining the various value for ONE item: gender (M/F), color (red, blue, green...) etc

Comment: This is exactly what was wrong with my code. I thougt I needed to add one setting to each radio button, but in fact only one was needed. I removed the second one and everything works fine, thanks! I would mark this as the correct answer if I could!

Answer (score 1):

This seems as a problem i had some time ago.
If I'm correct, you added two radio buttons to your form, by code you change the state of the other, for example

rdoButton1:
rdoButton2.checked = false

rdoButton2:
rdoButton1.checked = false

If this is the case, then thats your problem.
The strange things happen when you try to change the state of the first to true, rdoButton1 will change the state of rdoButton2 and therefor also cause a checkedChange event on the other, causing both to turn off.

The very (hilariously) simple solution to this:
Add a groupBox, place both radio buttons in the groupBox, delete the attached code to the radio buttons that change the others state and success.

The reason is that the groupBox have a build-in function that allows only one radio button to be checked at a time within itself, saving you the trouble of having to write the code yourself.

Comment: As I said in the comment to the previous response, this wasn't the problem that I had, but thanks anyway, since now I understand a bit more why that works this way.

Comment: That behavior has been a part of Windows since at least v3.0.  Radio Buttons are meant for mutually exclusive choices (and get their name from your car's radio tuner - it can only be tuned to one station at a time).  But it is not just GroupBoxes that have a special power, but any container control as well (Forms, TabPages, Panel etc). The good thing about GroupBoxes is that it shows the user which logical group the set of radios belong to.

Comment: the main form itself does not allow only one radio button to be on at a time.